# The method does not exist/is not available

Tags: json-rpc, web3.py

- web3py 5.15.0

i tried

```
w3.geth.personal.new_account('pass-phrase')
```

then get

```
{'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available'}
```

then figured out that i need to allow interacting with API's and did in terminal

```
geth --http.addr https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<#######> --http.api personal,eth,net,web3,admin,txpool
```

but still have the same error, what i did wrong? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should try command `web3.geth.personal.new_account(self, passphrase)` and added `--http` to command line.

Comment: i figured out that i cannot use ```geth``` method with hosted node, it is only for local node